node.js health api request test fails by zod validation?
I have a Node.js Express application that I'm trying to test using vitest and supertest. However, I'm encountering issues with missing environment variables. Here’s my setup:
Environment Configuration (environment.ts):
import z from 'zod';

const envSchema = z.object({
  HOST: z
    .string()
    .trim()
    .refine(
      host => host.startsWith('http') || host.startsWith('https'),
      'Invalid URL format',
    ),
  PORT: z.coerce
    .number({
      description:
        '.env files convert numbers to strings, therefore we have to enforce them to be numbers',
    })
    .positive()
    .max(65536, `options.port should be >= 0 and < 65536`)
    .default(3000),
  BASE_URL: z.string().trim().min(1).default('/api/v1'),
  DATABASE_URL: z
    .string()
    .url()
    .trim()
    .refine(url => url.startsWith('mongodb://'), 'Invalid Database URL format'),
  GITHUB_API_URL: z
    .string()
    .url()
    .trim()
    .refine(url => url.startsWith('https://'), 'Invalid Github URL format')
    .default('https://api.github.com'),
  GITHUB_SECRET: z.string().trim().min(1),
  LOG_DIR: z.string().optional(),
  CLIENT_URL: z
    .string()
    .url()
    .trim()
    .refine(url => url.startsWith('http://'), 'Invalid client URL format')
    .default('http://localhost:5173/'),
  CORS_ORIGIN: z.string().trim().min(1).default('*'),
  CORS_CREDENTIALS: z.boolean().default(true),
  NODE_ENV: z
    .enum(['development', 'production', 'test'])
    .default('development'),
});

const envServer = envSchema.safeParse({
  HOST: process.env.HOST,
  PORT: process.env.PORT,
  BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL,
  DATABASE_URL: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  REDIS_HOST: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
  REDIS_PORT: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
  REDIS_TTL: process.env.REDIS_TTL,
  REDIS_TIMEOUT: process.env.REDIS_TIMEOUT,
  GITHUB_API_URL: process.env.GITHUB_API_URL,
  GITHUB_SECRET: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
  LOG_DIR: process.env.LOG_DIR,
  CLIENT_URL: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
  CORS_ORIGIN: process.env.CORS_ORIGIN,
  CORS_CREDENTIALS: process.env.CORS_CREDENTIALS,
  NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV,
});

if (!envServer.success) {
  console.error(envServer.error.issues);
  throw new Error('There is an error with the server environment variables');
}

export const serverSchema = envServer.data;

Server Setup (server.ts):

import compression from 'compression';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import { Application, json, urlencoded } from 'express';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import hpp from 'hpp';
import swaggerJSDoc from 'swagger-jsdoc';
import swaggerUi from 'swagger-ui-express';

import { ErrorMiddleware } from '@/libs/shared/middlewares/error.middleware';

import logger from '@/utils/logger';

import { MongoDBInstance as dbConnection } from '@/config/database';
import { serverSchema } from '@/config/environment';

import applicationRoutes from '@/routes/index';

export class Server {
  private readonly app: Application;

  constructor(app: Application) {
    this.app = app;
  }

  public start(): void {
    this.connectDatabase();
    this.securityMiddleware(this.app);
    this.routesMiddleware(this.app);
    this.globalErrorHandler(this.app);
    this.startServer(this.app);
    this.initializeSwagger();
  }

  public getServer() {
    return this.app;
  }

  private securityMiddleware(app: Application): void {
    app.use(hpp());
    app.use(helmet());
    app.use(compression());
    app.use(json());
    app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '50mb' }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(
      cors({
        origin: serverSchema.CLIENT_URL,
        credentials: serverSchema.CORS_CREDENTIALS,
        optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
        methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
      }),
    );
  }

  private routesMiddleware(app: Application): void {
    applicationRoutes(app);
  }

  private globalErrorHandler(app: Application): void {
    app.use(ErrorMiddleware);
  }

  private connectDatabase(): void {
    dbConnection.getInstance();
  }

  private startServer(app: Application): void {
    logger.info(`------ NODE_ENV: ${serverSchema.NODE_ENV} ------`);
    logger.info(`Server has started with process ${process.pid}`);
    app.listen(serverSchema.PORT, () => {
      logger.info(`Server listening on port ${serverSchema.PORT}`);
    });
  }

  private initializeSwagger() {
    const options = {
      swaggerDefinition: {
        openapi: '3.0.3',
        info: {
          title: 'API Documentation',
          version: '1.0.0',
          description: 'REST API docs',
        },
        servers: [
          {
            url: `${serverSchema.HOST}:${serverSchema.PORT}${serverSchema.BASE_URL}`,
          },
        ],
      },
      apis: ['./swagger.yaml'],
    };

    const swaggerSpecs = swaggerJSDoc(options);
    this.app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpecs));

    logger.info(
      `Docs are available at ${serverSchema.HOST}:${serverSchema.PORT}/api-docs`,
    );
  }
}

Health Controller (health.controller.ts):
import express, { Application } from 'express';
import request from 'supertest';
import { beforeAll, describe, expect, it } from 'vitest';

import HealthController from '@/controllers/health.controller';

import { Server } from '@/server';

describe('HealthController', () => {
  let app: Application;

  beforeAll(() => {
    app = new Server(express()).getServer();

    const controller = new HealthController();
    app.get('/health', controller.getHealth);
  });

  it('GET /health should return status 200 and { health: "OK!" } when GET /health', async () => {
    const response = await request(app).get('/health');

    expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
    expect(response.body).toEqual({ health: 'OK!' });
  });
});

Routes Setup (health.router.ts):
import express, { Router } from 'express';

import HealthController from '@/controllers/health.controller';

export class HealthRoutes {
  private router: Router;

  constructor() {
    this.router = express.Router();
  }

  public getRoutes(): Router {
    const controller = new HealthController();

    this.router.get('/health', controller.getHealth);

    return this.router;
  }
}

export const healthRoutes = new HealthRoutes();

Router index.ts:
import { Application } from 'express';

import { serverSchema } from '@/config/environment';

import { healthRoutes } from './health.router';

const applicationRoutes = (app: Application) => {
  const routes = () => {
    app.use(serverSchema.BASE_URL, healthRoutes.getRoutes());
  };

  routes();
};

export default applicationRoutes;


When I run the tests I get the following error:
stderr | src/config/environment.ts:65:11
[
  {
    code: 'invalid_type',
    expected: 'string',
    received: 'undefined',
    path: [ 'HOST' ],
    message: 'Required'
  },
  {
    code: 'invalid_type',
    expected: 'string',
    received: 'undefined',
    path: [ 'DATABASE_URL' ],
    message: 'Required'
  },
  {
    code: 'invalid_type',
    expected: 'string',
    received: 'undefined',
    path: [ 'GITHUB_SECRET' ],
    message: 'Required'
  }
]

It appears that some environment variables are missing or not defined properly. How can I ensure all required environment variables are correctly loaded during testing and application runtime?
All the environment variables are set in my .env.development.local file.
I'm usign --env-file in package.json script to load environment variables.
The zod schema correctly defines and validates the variables.
How can I ensure that my Node.js application correctly loads and validates all required environment variables during tests and runtime?
What am I missing or doing incorrectly?

"are set in my .env.development.local file" - how do you normally load it? The name suggests you use dotenv or --env-file, but the question has no mention of it.

Hi. Yes I'm currently using --env-file in package.json script to load environment variables.

You'll have to load it manually with process.loadEnvFile in tests, but this can create problems because of possible env var conflicts, e.g. NODE_ENV

Ok, I've just found the error happens because I didn't set default values for those env variables in zod schema.
I added default values and the test pass correctly.
